# How to retain the original response from the observable in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, angular6, angular2-observables

I am subscribing to an observable to get the response from an external API. Then I perform another filtering function on it. But when I do so, it also filters the original response. I want to preserve the original response and also get the new filtered response. When I subscribe without implementing the getFilteredEntryByProv function, I get the full response in my 'Header Entries' console log. Once I had the filter function, the 'Header Entries; console log also gets updated.....Any suggestions?

```js
this.subscription = this.contentfulService.getContentfulEntry(this.headerEntryId, {locale: this.lang.toLowerCase()})
      .subscribe(res => {
      console.log('Header Entries:: ', res);
      this.filteredHeader = this.contentfulService.getFilteredEntryByProv(res, this.prov);
      console.log('Filtered Header:: ', this.filteredHeader);
```

Comment: can you add the source for the service functions?

Comment: Added. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getFilteredEntryByProv` you are modifying the response itself. `provObj.data = _.filter` modifies the `res.fields.data`.

You should just return filtered data from your function and leave original request as it is:

```
public getFilteredEntryByProv = (res, prov: string) => {
    return _.filter(res.fields.data, obj => _.includes(obj.prov, prov));
}
```